# Javascript. Передача функции в качестве аргумента другой функции

Tags: javascript, функции

Необходимо чтобы функция принимала другую функцию (func1) и неопределенное количество других аргументов. Искомая функция должна привязать переданные аргументы к функции func1 и вернуть получившуюся функцию. Вопрос возник именно в передаче аргументов функции func1. Код приведенный ниже выдает ошибку TypeError: fn is not a function. Как решается данная задача без передачи аргументов второй функции понятна, а вот здесь требуется помощь.

```
function func1(...args) {
    let result = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    result += args[i]
    }
    return result    
}

function func2(fn, ...arg) {
    let argArray = [...arg];
    return fn(argArray);       // TypeError: fn is not a function
}
```

Comment: как именно вызывается данная функция, что получается такая ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function func1(...arg) {
  let result = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arg.length; i++) {
    result += arg[i];
  }
  return result;
}

function func2(fn, ...arg) {
  let argArray = [...arg];
  return fn.apply(this, argArray);
}

console.log(func2(func1, 1, 2, 3, 4));

// привязать переданные аргументы к функции func1 и вернуть получившуюся функцию:
function func3(fn, ...arg) {
  let argArray = [...arg];
  return function() { return fn.apply(this, argArray) };
}

var fn3 = func3(func1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
console.log(fn3());
```

Comment: Спасибо! Совсем забыл что есть apply!

Comment: @Fidel.Marti, `apply` не нужен, раз ты все равно везде `...` используешь